# Batch file to copy files from server to desktop according to date

Tags: batch, file-transfer, robocopy

I will explain what I´m trying to get up and runing.
I have a folder on the server containing several subfolders and zip archives in those folders.
The string of the server is like:

```
\\server1\groups\MSA\Local DTB\AT\2014\2014 06\**.zip
\\server1\groups\MSA\Local DTB\BE\2014\2014 06\**.zip
```

and so on...
There are numerous folders for each couńtry (in the string above the AT, BE and so on)

Each month a new folder is created. So for example 2014 07 but the previous months stay also.
I would need a command that would determine the latest zip files and copy those into my specified location.

Till now I used a simple xcopy command

```
 xcopy /s "\\server1\groups\MSA\Local DTB\AT\2014\2014 06\*.zip" "C:\Users\mk8610\Desktop\FINALS PRE VALERIE\JUN16\MSA"
```

But its kind of clumsy to overwrite the 2014 06 to the actual month format each month.
Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Dave

Comment: Welcome to SU!  We're not a script-writing service.  What have you got so far?  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

/D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
              If no date is given, copies only those files whose
              source time is newer than the destination time.

that command allows you to specific a date of the files without examples files i cant write the script for you

Comment: OK, the /D works just fine. But how should I change the command line for the source file. That is, when the folder changes from 2014 06 to for example 2014 07 and so on? So that the batch will copy only the latest file from the newest folder?

Comment: xcopy /s "\\server1\groups\MSA\Local DTB\AT\2014\2014 06\*.zip" "C:\Users\mk8610\Desktop\FINALS PRE VALERIE\JUN16\MSA" is this the commadn you use? if so xcopy /s /D 7-1-2014 "\\server1\groups\MSA\Local DTB\AT\2014\2014 06\*.zip" "C:\Users\mk8610\Desktop\FINALS PRE VALERIE\JUN16\MSA" but if you are using separate folders for each month  aint sure it will find the files